# Office Solutions for Visual Community 2013?

Tags: microsoft-office, visual-studio-2013, developer-tools

I'm trying to learn how to create Office Add-Ins, but the Development tools don't appear to be apart of VS Community.  Everything I've read is saying community is not a cutdown version of VS.

**Microsoft Office Developer Tools** check box is not an option during setup.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: [Just download them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2014/03/03/office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2013-march-2014-update.aspx)

Comment: Community supports add-ons that doesn't mean the Addon you require is supported, if it isn't, then you are out of luck.

Comment: @Raystafarian Thanks a ton... Don't know why all my google searching wouldn't bring me to that beautiful site. Make that an 'Answer' so you can get credit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this was introduced, MS had a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2014/03/03/office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2013-march-2014-update.aspx) describing it and how it can be downloaded - it was not included in the VS installer. Installation link at the bottom.